# utorrent server, libssl.so.1.0.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Tags: server, utorrent

got problem to launch uTorrent server:

```
# utserver -settingspath /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/
utserver: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64


# ldd /opt/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/utserver
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf7781000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => not found
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => not found
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0xf7757000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf773b000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xf7732000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf76ec000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf76cf000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf7520000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7783000)
```

on:

```
Linux SNAME 4.0.0-040000-generic #201504121935 
SMP Sun Apr 12 23:36:33 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
```

Is it cuz utorrent and libssl problems? or just i got libssl in wrong architecture (x32 insted of x64) ?

How to fix it or maybe just i should leave this stuff and try to install some utorrent-server alternative insted?

I already tried to isntall libssl v9.8 and some tricks with ln -s. Now i got wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 error.

Comment: there are better alternatives ... just dump utorrent ;)

Comment: yes, i noticed.. . I used utorrent-server long time ago, but right now im fighting too long to launch this stuff - so i just decided to maybe install & configure deluge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the 32 bit version of libssl

```
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0:i386
```

Note all the other libraries are 32 bit.  The libcrypto should be in that package also.

Comment: This didn't work for me out of the box - required running ```sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt-get update``` for it to add that particular architecture to dpkg's registry. Without doing that, it complains of a non-matching regex.